# fuse different paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

Suppose that we have four nodes a, b, c, and d. For example :

```
\coordinate [label=left:a]  (a) at (0,4);
\coordinate [label=right:b] (b) at (4,4);
\coordinate [label=left:c]  (c) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:d] (d) at (4,0);
```

Let's draw some arbitrary paths between every couple in {(a,b), (a,c), (c,d), (d,b), (b,a)}. Example :

```
\draw [red]    (a) to [bend left=30]                   (c);
\draw [blue]   (b) to [out=45, in= -50]                (a);
\draw [orange] (c) to [controls=+(45:6) and +(170:6)]  (d);
\draw [green!60!black,decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=1pt}] (d) -- (b);
```

[image]

To my knowledge

```
\path (a) -- (c) -- (d) -- (b) -- cycle;
```

is considered as one path, so therefore we can fill the area inside this path; But in the example above we have four paths and therefore the fill area is senseless for tikZ.

**My Question** : Is it possible to fuse all of paths (in example) to create one fillable path like `\fill [blue!10] (a) -- (c) -- (d) -- (b) -- cycle;` or something else ? In other way, I want to hatch the surface S.

**All code :**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\mathversion{bold}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=left:a]  (a) at (0,4);
\coordinate [label=right:b] (b) at (4,4);
\coordinate [label=left:c]  (c) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:d] (d) at (4,0);

\foreach \p in {a,b,c,d}{
\fill[red] (\p) circle (2pt);}

\draw [red]    (a) to [bend left=30]                   (c);
\draw [blue]   (b) to [out=45, in= -50]                (a);
\draw [orange] (c) to [controls=+(45:6) and +(170:6)]  (d);
\draw [green!60!black,decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=1pt}] (d) -- (b);
\node at (2,2.5) {$S$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To be more clear, I encountered this problem when creating a (breakable) tcolorbox

[image]

I want to fill the empty surface S, but with four paths I cannot do it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course. You cannot draw the path in different colors, but certainly you can combine the stretches to be filled, and draw the colored stretches either explicitly separately, or via `edge`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\mathversion{bold}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=left:a]  (a) at (0,4);
\coordinate [label=right:b] (b) at (4,4);
\coordinate [label=left:c]  (c) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=right:d] (d) at (4,0);

\foreach \p in {a,b,c,d}{
\fill[red] (\p) circle (2pt);}
\path[decoration={snake,pre length=1pt},fill=blue!20]
 (a) to [bend left=30]                   (c)
 to [controls=+(45:6) and +(170:6)](d)
 decorate {  -- (b)}  
 to [out=45, in= -50]   cycle;
\draw [red]    (a) to [bend left=30]                   (c);
\draw [blue]   (b) to [out=45, in= -50]                (a);
\draw [orange] (c) to [controls=+(45:6) and +(170:6)]  (d);
\draw [green!60!black,decorate,decoration={snake,pre length=1pt}] (d) -- (b);
\node at (2,2.5) {$S$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and adding `even odd rule`, i.e.

```
\path[decoration={snake,pre length=1pt},fill=blue!20,even odd rule]
 (a) to [bend left=30]                   (c)
 to [controls=+(45:6) and +(170:6)](d)
 decorate {  -- (b)}  
 to [out=45, in= -50]   cycle;
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: @schrödingers if you don't mind, i want to ask about two Special cases: 
**1.if we want to draw nothing between two node and conserve the path** for example not drawing the blue and orange curves, but conserve the whole path (to fill it later); 
**2.** __save the decoration__ you can see that if we use the following code : 
`[d1/.style={decoration={random steps,segment length=1pt,amplitude=3pt}}] \draw [blue,d1,fill=blue!10] (a) decorate { -- (c)} to  (d) decorate { -- (b)} to cycle; 
\draw [red,d1] (a) decorate { -- (c)}; `
We will get bad results

Comment: @BahaedineMadir I do not understand the first point. The second is not an executable code, but I think that you are saying that there will always be new random numbers, so random decorations do not match when redrawn. This is correct. I think that there is a chance that one can work with the `save path` key. However, as this deviates quite a bit from the original question, I'd kindly ask you to use a new question for these follow-up questions, in which you explain the problem as well as in this nice question, which is very clear and useful.

Comment: @schrödingers, ok i will; thank you!